# Is there references of javascript GUI automation on yosemite(OS X 10.10)

Tags: javascript, macos, user-interface, automation, javascript-automation

I have installed os x 10.10 yosemite and I want to write a 
javascript to test an application automatically.

Is there any javascript examples which I can references now?

Comment: Yosemite is beta only. So its off-topic.

Comment: I don't know if this question is still active, but here is a documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508

Comment: Take a look at http://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js

Comment: This article explains it and the author has many examples. http://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js

Answer (score 1):

There is also a introductory video on the [WWDC2014 site](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/), but you have to be a registered developer to access it. That said it pretty much covers what is in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html) that was referenced in the other comments.

There is also a [good discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7862973) going on on Hacker News about it.

That said my first experiences of it have been pretty frustrating. The documentation is woeful (that said Applescript documentation has always been pretty shoddy)and it is very difficult to work out what's going on because of the cryptic error messages.

I even got one the other day which said `Script too silly to run`.

I hope that when Yosemite is released there will be more documentation / example code released but I wouldn't hold your breath.